# Automapper base class mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

For AutoMapper, I've implemented the following which works, but has repeated mapping code:

```
cfg.CreateMap<RmsOelEntryUnlinkedPersonInputDto, AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOfBirth, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateType(src.DateOfBirth)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveFromTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveFromTime)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveToTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveToTime)));

cfg.CreateMap<RmsOelEntryUnlinkedAddressInputDto, AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveFromTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveFromTime)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveToTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveToTime)));
```

Both `RmsOelEntryUnlinkedPersonInputDto` and `RmsOelEntryUnlinkedAddressInputDto` are inherited from `RmsOelEntryInvolvedEntityBaseDto` and this base class has the properties `EffectiveFromTime` and `EffectiveToTime`.

I don't want the to have to repeatedly map `EffectiveFromTime` and `EffectiveToTime` as seen above.

However, `AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked` and `AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked` are autogenerated and don't have a base class. Therefore I don't see how I can use AutoMapper's "Include" mapping option.

How do I optimise this to remove the repeated mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar situation and have resorted to helper Extension methods. I customized for your case :

```
internal static class CommonMapperExtensions
{
     internal static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapCommonFields<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> m)
         where TSource : RmsOelEntryInvolvedEntityBaseDto
         where TDestination : IEffective
     {
         return m
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveFromTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveFromTime)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EffectiveToTime, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateTimeType(src.EffectiveToTime)));                
     }
}
```

Then configuration would look like this :

```
cfg.CreateMap<RmsOelEntryUnlinkedPersonInputDto, AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked>()
    .MapCommonFields()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOfBirth, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => FormatDateType(src.DateOfBirth)));

cfg.CreateMap<RmsOelEntryUnlinkedAddressInputDto, AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked>()
    .MapCommonFields();
```

If `AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked` and `AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked` are autogenerated I would assume they are partial.

Then you could make common interface for those classes :

```
public interface IEffective 
{
     DateTime EffectiveFromTime {get; set;}
     DateTime EffectiveToTime {get; set;}
}

public partial AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked
    : IEffective { }

public partial AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked
    : IEffective { }
```

Comment: Thanks. In your extension method I see the destination is constrained as AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedPersonUnlinked, but it would also need to map AddNewOELEntryInvolvedEntitiesUnlinkedInvolvedAddressUnlinked. How would that work ?

Comment: See updated answer :) Open question if generated classes are partial?

Comment: Of course, doing this would pay off if this case is more common than two mappings.

Comment: They are indeed partial and your solution works very well; though I needed to modify the code to reference the 'm' object inside the extension method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, I fixed bug in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TBaseModel
{
    public void ConfigureMapFrom(IMappingExpression<TEntity, TBaseModel> mapping)
    {
        // ... mappings
    }
}

public class TModel : TBaseModel
{
    public void ConfigureMapFrom(IMappingExpression<TEntity, TModel> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IncludeBase<TEntity, TBaseModel>();

        // ... other mappings
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context to your answer?